# More efficient query using foreign key where in table 1 but not in table 2

Tags: mysql

I've got three tables: Test, Amp, and Fluorescence. Test is a foreign key to both Amp and Fluorescence, which are both join tables. Fluorescence has between 50 and 100 rows per test_id, while Amp typically has fewer than 2.

I need to get the list of distinct test_id's that are in Fluorescence but not in Amp. Both subqueries also specify a channel.

Right now, I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT test FROM db_test WHERE test NOT IN 
(SELECT test_id FROM db_amp WHERE channel=0)
AND test IN (SELECT test.id FROM db_fluorescence WHERE channel=0);
```

While this query works, it takes .5 seconds. That's already longer than I'd like and it's just going to get longer as the database grows.

I'm rather new to SQL, so I know there's a more efficient way to do this.

I'm also considering a work-around, such as adding a field to the Test table, which indicates the status:

```
1. 0 - In neither Amp/Fluorescence
2. 1 - In Amp
3. 2 - In Fluorescence
4. 3 - In Both
```

Then querying against it:

`SELECT test FROM db_test WHERE ch0_grade = 2;`

While this would certainly be faster, I'm of the mind that I ought to be able to find a better solution via improving my original query. Additionally, I think this second option breaks normality, as that field is entirely derivative of other information within the database.

Answer (score 0):

This query should be accurate and performant enough with the indexes:

```html
SELECT test
FROM db_test
JOIN db_fluorescence ON db_fluorescence.test_id = db_test.test
LEFT JOIN db_amp ON db_amp.test_id = db_test.test
WHERE db_amp.test_id IS NULL;
```

Since we need the query to be performant, I would add secondary hash indexes which would speed up the execution.

Indexes are used to retrieve data from the database very fast. The users cannot see the indexes, they are just used to speed up searches/queries.

```html
CREATE INDEX index1
ON db_fluorescence(test_id);

CREATE INDEX index2
ON db_test(test_id);

CREATE INDEX index3
ON db_amp(test_id);
```

Note: Updating a table with indexes takes more time than updating a table without (because the indexes also need an update). So, only create indexes on columns that will be frequently searched against.

Comment: I tried indexing the foreign key (test_id) in both Amp and Fluorescence with negligible difference in performance. Again, the join did not improve speed, however, it may when the database is much larger?

Comment: Indexes are used to retrieve data from the database very fast. While, you may not notice the speed for a small size of data but with increasing datasets, you can test the performance of the query with and without the indexes. You will find the indexes approach would be much faster in a retrieval of data. All this is dependant on the query plan the SQL Engine picks up for your SQL execution. Hence, you can look at the query execution plans and make indexes accordingly. If you are new to SQL and want a workaround, go ahead with creating an index on db_test too if that's not the primary key.

Comment: I've gone on with the indexes. I trust that as the database grows it will show it's efficiency. I didn't index db_test, as test is the primary key for that table. For now, I was able to split up another section of code (HTML) so that it loads the first half of the page while the query is being executed, rather than after, so the performance is less of an issue now.